# Elastic - Is it possible to change the scope of a nested aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

### Context

**Elastic 6.0.0**

I have the following structure:

```
{
  "age": 24,
  "blood": 450,
  "iv": 700,
  "job": "boss",
  "damage": "cut,
  "complications": {
    "days": 4
  },
  "diagnostics": [
    {"flavour": "lemon"}, {"flavour": "coco"}
  ]
}
```

I have been trying different aggregations, always aggregating average fields at the end, like [this](https://gist.github.com/sebastialonso/b8958417d62fa94b24d215fdcae1a72c).

And the results return fine, actually great. As you can see in the link, the averages aggregations at the end is the most crucial part of the whole aggregation. scheme.

So far, I have find out that **they must be the last step** of the process. Otherwise, I wouldn't get the correct averages values for the desired level of data aggregation.

### Problem

My issue comes at the point where I have to add a nested aggregation, example [here](https://gist.github.com/sebastialonso/b82cc8aa79e9d3139eaf22b8ca983567).

If I   add the nested aggregation (grouping for diagnostic flavours) at the end of the aggregation scheme, and then add the averages aggregation as another aggregation over the nested aggregation, all I get is null values. 
Which is completely correct!, given that nor `blood`, nor `iv` fields are part of the nested `diagnostics` field.

### Question

> is there a way to change the "scope" of the averages aggregation so
>   that it can calculate the averages over the fields of the main object,
>   and not the nested one, while I keep the nested aggregation in the scheme?

I have searched through the documentation, but no one seems to get my problem, so I'm thinking that maybe there's something wrong in what I'm doing.

Comment: So you want to group by the nested field but aggregate on the non-nested fields If i understand you correctly. I think what you want is reverse nested aggregation. See here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html

Comment: As I said, if the query in my response is not what you are looking for, tell us how you want your results to look like, not thinking about an approach - `changing the "scope" of averages` - but about the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As somebody already said, what you need is the `reverse_nested` aggregation. According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html), it's exactly the thing for "changing scopes" in subaggregations. Based on what you have explained, I think you need to supply the empty object to the `reverse_nested` aggregation.

I hope this puts you in the right track for solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would have loved to see a desired output, because I am not sure I understood the requirement. I attempted a trivial solution, but as I said, you were not explaining this right.

```
  "aggs": {
    "job": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "job"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "damage": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "damage"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "nested_diagnostic_flavour": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "diagnostics"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "flavour": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "diagnostics.flavour"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "iv": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "iv"
              }
            },
            "blood": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "blood"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```